# The Effect of Accelerometer Position on Modal Analysis of a Cantilever

Tags: beam, sensors, modal-analysis

We have obtained the first two vibration modal frequencies of a composite cantilever (33 gm). We placed the accelerometer (3.4 gm) near the fixed end and the two frequencies were F<sub>1</sub>=30 Hz and F<sub>2</sub> = 256 Hz.

We need an analytical formula to predict these frequencies and the effect of the accelerometer mass position on frequencies.

Comment: The accelerometer won't have much effect because it is near the base. You could use Rayleigh Ritz, FEA, or here's a paper with the analytical solution  TY  - JOUR
AU  - Skoblar, Ante
AU  - Zigulic, Roberto
AU  - Braut, Sanjin
AU  - Blažević, Sebastijan
PY  - 2017/01/01
SP  - 367
EP  - 373
T1  - Dynamic response to harmonic transverse excitation of cantilever Euler-Bernoulli beam carrying a point mass
VL  - 45
DO  - 10.5937/fmet1703367S
JO  - FME Transactions
ER  -

Comment: @GregLocock Thanks but is there any single equation giving Natural frequency for the case i have highlighted ?

Comment: Yes, in that paper. Normally we don't calculate it, we just put another accelerometer alongside the first and so see how much more that shifts the frequency.

Comment: @GregLocock Still need a crisp formula involving Accelerometer distance as a parameter

Comment: So, read the paper, plug your values into the equation, and there you go.

Comment: @GregLocock The paper is all about complex expressions ... what i need is similar to e.g. omega = (k/m)^0.5

Comment: I've suggested 3 approaches. The rigorous analysis in that paper leads to a complex equation. That is often the case even with simple problems. Specifically, you are mixing a distributed system with a point mass system, I have no expectation that a simple equation would result. root k/m works because it only looks at one frequency. So, use FEA, Rayleigh-Ritz, or plug numbers into the equations in that paper. For a mass M at the tip f=1/(2 pi)*sqrt((3 E I)/(L^3*(M+.24mass_beam)))^.5 for the fundamental